# graphics rectangles names and positions

Tags: c#

I want to be able to draw hundreds of rectangles (label boxes or text boxes or rectangles with lines).  These rectangles will be placed according to a physical representation of bays in a car park.  what i would like to do is label the the rectangles individually (each one will be different so as to make it unique) when the user moves the mouse over (hover) a rectangle, the name of the rectangle must be returned to th program for processing in which information will be accessed from the database according to the rectangles name and location.

Does anyone know of ways to draw multiple rectangles/labelboxes or such and return their names and or co-ordinates?

Comment: Make the question clear. What you want to achieve?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? Silverlight? etc.

Comment: using winforms i suppose,  i don't know ASP.Net

Answer (score 1):

This is quite complex task. But you Can start from representing your Rectangle in OO way:

```
interface IDrawable 
{
    void Draw();

    // Check for obj under location
    IDrawable HitTest(Point a_loc);
}

class Rectangle : IDrawable
{
   public Point RectLocation { get; private set; }

   public void Draw()
   {
     // Draw Logic using Grapsics -> should be simple you can use existing in.Net Rectangle class
   };

   public IDrawable HitTest(Point a_loc)
   {
     // match's locations
   }
}

// Drawing on custom User Control (surface)

foreach (var oRect in Rectangles)
{
   oRect.Draw();
}

// Mouse -> just handle mouse move event invoke HitTest() with current point
```

And similar this for labels.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming WinForms or WPF: I'd create a control that can "draw" a bay in a car park. Then I'd position the required controls in my view.

The task of obtaining information about the "selected" bay is then trivial, as they don't overlap and mouse events will be thrown for the control the mouse is in.

I'm sure the information about which bay is where is stored somewhere, so it should be a trivial task adding a unique key to each entry (for example a "bay number"). You could then pass the bay number to the control upon construction and later access the bay number of the control holding the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you're looking for..

```
//Random rv = new Random();
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Use for loop if you want multiple..
        Graphics surfac = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen p = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Blue, 2.0f);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10,10,100,100);
        // Increment these values to get bays placed as rectangles

        surfac.DrawRectangle(p, rect);
    }
```